# How can I include normal php script in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I want to include normal php script that I have made before for another project in DefaultController.

```
public function indexAction()
{       
            include('./GenFunctions.php');
```

then I put GenFunctinos.php in the same directory as DefaultController,
but it shows 'failed to open stream'

How can I include this script?

I understood this is the illegular way to include in the perspective of symfony2.

But I want to do this to reuse the script.
please help me.

Comment: Use the file's absolute path: `__DIR__ . '/GenFunctions.php'` or `/path/to/GenFunctions.php`

Comment: is it a class or just some functions ? maybe you should refactor it to a class using namespaces and integrate it with composer ...

Comment: 100% with @nifr. Composer is the way to go when adding libs to a symfony2 project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can autoload this file with composer.

http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/GenFunctions.php"]
    }
}
```